# hello, i want to make screens like this in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I implement the buttons on top?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read flutter cookbook there are a lot of useful examples.

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list